# Usermin unable to access from https://username:20000/

Tags: router, webmin

I installed webmin and browse GUI interface with URL https://simon:10000. But there was problem with usermin..
I tried to list routing table with command below of port 10000

```
root@simon:~# netstat -an | grep :10000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:10000         127.0.0.1:52248         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52246         127.0.1.1:10000         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52248         127.0.1.1:10000         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:10000         127.0.0.1:52246         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*
```

But trying

```
root@simon:~# netstat -an | grep :20000
```

gives no tables for port..

This is what i have tried so far.

What i am missing.

Comment: and what happens when you use `https://localhost:10000/`  or `http://localhost:10000/`

Comment: localhost or 127.0.0.1 or simon (username) are configured same as defined in /etc/hosts. It redirects to webmin login console

Comment: First you have to configure usermin within the webmin interface

Comment: so simon is both username and hostname? Don't get confused ;)